# Gradient descent for linear regression is not working

Tags: java, machine-learning, statistics, artificial-intelligence, gradient-descent

I tried making a program for linear regression using gradient descent for some sample data. The theta values that I get do not give the best fit for the data. I have already normalized the data.

```
public class OneVariableRegression {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double x1[] = {-1.605793084, -1.436762233, -1.267731382, -1.098700531, -0.92966968, -0.760638829, -0.591607978, -0.422577127, -0.253546276, -0.084515425, 0.084515425, 0.253546276, 0.422577127, 0.591607978, 0.760638829, 0.92966968, 1.098700531, 1.267731382, 1.436762233, 1.605793084};  
        double y[] = {0.3, 0.2, 0.24, 0.33, 0.35, 0.28, 0.61, 0.38, 0.38, 0.42, 0.51, 0.6, 0.55, 0.56, 0.53, 0.61, 0.65, 0.68, 0.74, 0.87};
        double theta0 = 0.5;
        double theta1 = 0.5;
        double temp0;
        double temp1;
        double alpha = 1.5;
        double m = x1.length;
        System.out.println(m);
        double derivative0 = 0;
        double derivative1 = 0;
        do {
                    for (int i = 0; i < x1.length; i++) {
            derivative0 = (derivative0 + (theta0 + (theta1 * x1[i]) - y[i])) * (1/m);
            derivative1 = (derivative1 + (theta0 + (theta1 * x1[i]) - y[i])) * (1/m) * x1[i];
        }
          temp0 = theta0 - (alpha * derivative0);
          temp1 = theta1 - (alpha * derivative1);
          theta0 = temp0;
          theta1 = temp1;
          //System.out.println("Derivative0 = " + derivative0);
          //System.out.println("Derivative1 = " + derivative1);
        }
        while (derivative0 > 0.0001 || derivative1 > 0.0001);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("theta 0 = " + theta0);
        System.out.println("theta 1 = " + theta1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't test out your code, but my understanding is that gradient descent is not guaranteed to always find the absolute minimum/maximum (instead finding a local one).  So this could be a limitation in the method you are using, rather than a quirk in the Java code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  Specifically, include the output you got and the expected output, as well as your rationale for believing that you would find the global best fit; are you sure that the solution space is properly convex?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You're right in general, only thing is: from the derivative in the code we know it's the _squared error function_, which is convex (hence its popularity for linear regression)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes, it's convex.

The derivative you're using comes from the squared error function, which is convex, hence accepts no local minimums other than the one global minimum. (In fact, this type of problem can even accepts a closed-form solution called the *normal equation*, it's just not numerically tractable for large problems, hence the use of gradient descent)

And the correct answer is around `theta0 =  0.4895` and `theta1 = 0.1652`, this is trivial to check on any statistical computing environment. (See bottom of answer if you're skeptical)

**Below I point out the mistakes in your code, after fixing the mistakes, you'll get the correct answer above within 4 decimals places.**

### Problems with your implementation:

So you are right to expect it to converge global minimum, but you have problems in the implementation

Each time you recalculate the `derivative_i`, you forgot to reset it to 0 (what you were doing was accumulating the derivative across iterations in the `do{}while()`

You need this in the do while loop

```
do {                                                                    
   derivative0 = 0;                                                      
   derivative1 = 0;

   ...
}
```

Next is this

```
derivative0 = (derivative0 + (theta0 + (theta1 * x1[i]) - y[i])) * (1/m);
derivative1 = (derivative1 + (theta0 + (theta1 * x1[i]) - y[i])) * (1/m) * x1[i];
```

The `x1[i]` factor should be applied to the `(theta0 + (theta1 * x1[i]) - y[i]))` alone.

Your attempt is slightly confusing, so let's write it in a clearer manner as below, which is a lot closer to its mathematical equation `(1/m)sum(y_hat_i - y_i)x_i`:

```
// You need fresh vars, don't accumulate the derivatives across gradient descent iterations

derivative0 = 0;                                                      
derivative1 = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {                       
    derivative0 += (1/m) * (theta0 + (theta1 * x1[i]) - y[i]);          
    derivative1 += (1/m) * (theta0 + (theta1 * x1[i]) - y[i])*x1[i];    
}
```

That should get you close enough, however, I find your learning rate alpha to be a tad big. When it's *too big*, your gradient descent will have trouble *zeroing in* no your global optimum, it will hang around there, but won't quite be there.

```
double alpha = 0.5;
```

### Confirm the results

Run it and compare it to the answer from a statistics software

Here's a [gist on github](https://gist.github.com/bakkal/ec3fe2d6b2d98dc7f1c01d8d30489e3d) of your .java file.

```
➜  ~ javac OneVariableRegression.java && java OneVariableRegression                                                                                                                           
20.0

theta 0 = 0.48950064086914064
theta 1 = 0.16520139788757973
```

I compared it with R

```
> x
 [1] -1.60579308 -1.43676223 -1.26773138 -1.09870053 -0.92966968 -0.76063883
 [7] -0.59160798 -0.42257713 -0.25354628 -0.08451543  0.08451543  0.25354628
[13]  0.42257713  0.59160798  0.76063883  0.92966968  1.09870053  1.26773138
[19]  1.43676223  1.60579308
> y
 [1] 0.30 0.20 0.24 0.33 0.35 0.28 0.61 0.38 0.38 0.42 0.51 0.60 0.55 0.56 0.53
[16] 0.61 0.65 0.68 0.74 0.87
> lm(y ~ x)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
     0.4895       0.1652
```

Now your code gives the correct answer to at least 4 decimals.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's an error in your formulae.  for some reason, you included derivative0 and 1 in the multiplications.  This seriously skewed the results.  Simply remove the extra parentheses and try again:

```
derivative0 = derivative0 + (theta0 + (theta1 * x1[i]) - y[i]) * (1/m);
derivative1 = derivative1 + (theta0 + (theta1 * x1[i]) - y[i]) * (1/m) * x1[i];
```

Output:

```
20.0
Derivative0 = 0.010499999999999995
Derivative1 = 0.31809711251208517
Derivative0 = 0.0052500000000000185
Derivative1 = 0.1829058398064968
Derivative0 = -0.007874999999999993
Derivative1 = -0.2129262545589219

theta 0 = 0.4881875
theta 1 = 0.06788495336050987
```

Is this more like what you expected?

Comment: Your theta0 value is correct but the theta1 value is slightly off. I think this happens because the derivative values need to be reset to 0, as suggested in the other answer. I agree that the extra parentheses skewed my results.